# Python tkinter adding a .exe file to a frame inside of the program

Tags: python, tkinter, operating-system, command, exe

for my graduation project I am making a arcade GUI in Python 3.7. Now I got a little stuck here, what I am trying to do is so when you open a new page (by clicking the button) i want it so that a executable file (ex: pacman) will play inside the frame **so not with the 'os' method**.

Is there a possibility to make it like when you click on the button 'play' that the game starts inside of the window/frame instead of opening it outside of the program?

Here is a piece of my code:

def **init**(self,master):

Frame.**init**(self, master)

```
    self.frameName="GamePage"
    backgr = Image.open("Gamepage_background.png")
    render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(backgr)
    background = Label(self, image=render)
    background.image = render
    background.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

    Button(self, text = "Go back to main page",font=('Arcade Interlaced',15),bg="black",fg="white",command=lambda: master.changeFrame(0)).pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor = W , pady= 15, padx= 15)

    Button(self, text = "Pac Man",font=('Arcade Interlaced',30),bg="purple",fg="white",command = master.openPacman).place(anchor = CENTER, relx= 0.27, rely= 0.275, width = 475, height = 125) #voorlopig in orde in 1920x1080

    Button(self, text = "Space Invaders",font=('Arcade Interlaced',30),bg="purple",fg="white",command= master.openSpaceinvaders,  wraplength = 350, justify = CENTER).place(anchor = CENTER, relx= 0.74, rely= 0.275, width = 475, height = 125)'''
```

What I want is when i click on one of the two games it would open up a new frame with the game playing inside the frame and not externaly.

Thank you and i hope i find the answer soon!

Comment: Are these games that you want to embed written in python with tkinter, or are they random programs plucked from the internet that you have no control over?

Comment: Have you done any research? This site has a few questions related to embedded games, such as https://stackoverflow.com/q/20483983/7432

Comment: @BryanOakley the games are python program which are not made with tkinter but i can acces the code and there is also a exe linked to it.